# Ecto assoc on empty list

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to get the language of a bunch of articles, from which I have the ID.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Repo.all(from a in Article, where: a.id in ^article_ids) |> Ecto.assoc(:language) |> Repo.all
```

This works fine when the first call to Repo returns results. But if the first Repo call return an empty list, I get an argument error:

`** (ArgumentError) cannot retrieve association :language for empty list`

What's a nice way to solve this problem in Phoenix?

Comment: How about `Repo.all(from a in Article, join: l in assoc(a, :language), where: a.id in ^article_ids, select: l)`?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you'd do this in an elegant way using `Ecto.assoc/1`, but your query can be rewritten using a `JOIN` query like this:

```
Repo.all(
  from a in Article,
    join: l in assoc(a, :language),
    where: a.id in ^article_ids,
    select: l
)
```